# Sum of different slices rows and column

Tags: python, pandas

I have pandas DataFrame df and three arrays columns_list, lower_boarder and upper_boarder all have the same shape. I want to find array with shape as input arrays. For i-th sum in array I need sum of i-th column from i-th lower_boarder and i-th upper_boarder. Is it possible to do in pandas way?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(0, 10).repeat(5).reshape(10, 5), columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5'])


      col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
0     0     0     0     0     0
1     1     1     1     1     1
2     2     2     2     2     2
3     3     3     3     3     3
4     4     4     4     4     4
5     5     5     5     5     5
6     6     6     6     6     6
7     7     7     7     7     7
8     8     8     8     8     8
9     9     9     9     9     9

columns_list = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col1']
lower_boarder = [2, 3, 5, 6]
upper_boarder = [4, 5, 6, 9]

sum = []
for i in range(len(columns_list)):
    sum.append(df.loc[lower_boarder[i]:upper_boarder[i], columns_list[i]].sum())
```

How can I do it without itteration? If shapes of columns_list is different?

Comment: Don't use `sum` as a variable name since it's a built-in function and overwriting it causes a myriad of problems...

Answer (score 0):

Create DataFrame only by columns by `columns_list` by [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) and then compare `arange` by length of DataFrame by `lower_boarder, upper_boarder` with numpy broadcasting, if not match generate `0` by [`DataFrame.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html), last sum columns to `Series`:

```
df1 = df.reindex(columns_list, axis=1)
m1 = np.arange(len(df1))[:, None] >= np.array(lower_boarder) 
m2 = np.arange(len(df1))[:, None] <= np.array(upper_boarder) 

#if default index
m1 = df1.index.to_numpy()[:, None] >= np.array(lower_boarder) 
m2 = df1.index.to_numpy()[:, None] <= np.array(upper_boarder)
```

---

```
s = df1.where(m1 & m2, 0).sum()
print (s)
col1     9
col2    12
col3    11
col1    30
dtype: int64
```

Numpy alternative with [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
a = np.where(m1 & m2, df1, 0).sum(axis=0).tolist()
print (a)
[9, 12, 11, 30]
```

Comment: Thank you, np broadcasting is usefull. But I got _ArrayMemoryError at m1=df1.index. columns_list length is 975368, and it has a lot of duplicates, so in my case reindex dataframe costs a lot of time and memory. And I used np.arange only for example, I have random index and values, so first m1 = np.arange... doesn't look  working for random. Itteration through columns_list is still better.